# Creating and changing attributes in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a WYSIWYG text editor. The class for the textarea is `.textContents` Before submitting the textarea, I want a function to be run. This function is called `imageOptimize()` What this function does is basically take the original image path of the image and place it in a variable called original. Next, the `src` attribute is given a default background. Afterwards, a `data-src` value is created with the path of original. Then we take original's file name and create another `data` attribute called `data-mobile-src` with a specific pathway followed by the original file name. This code is shown here:

```
    $('.social_properties_form').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();

            imgOptimize();

                $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: '',
                  data: new FormData(this),
                  processData: false,
                  contentType: false,
                  success: function(data) {
                 window.location = "/profiles/articles.php";
                  }
                });
                }
        })

function imgOptimize(){
    $(".textContents img").each(function(){
        var original = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).attr('src', '/media/assets/loading-background.jpg');

        $(this).attr('data-src', original);

        var fileName = original.split('/').pop();

        $(this).attr('data-mobile-src', '/stories/media/images/mobile/' + fileName);
    });
}
```

However, upon submission of the form this does not happen. It's as if the function is never executed. The textarea's image attributes do not change and the original is stored in the database.

Comment: Can you post your markup and give us a working demo?

Comment: everything you've provided seems to work http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWVpbj

Comment: @MichaelCoker I guess it's just not working on the back-end of things when I insert it into the table. I wonder why

Comment: @MichaelCoker Do you know how I can update the textarea's contents using PHP, like after I've changed the src attributes how do I give the textarea the updated content?

Comment: Your `$.ajax()` changes `window.location`. I'm assuming that on the resulting page, something like `<textarea><?php echo $someoutput; ?></textarea>`. But if you want to update a textarea on the same page without following the `window.location` change, you wouldn't use PHP, you would use the result of your `$.ajax()` to return the data for the textarea and use JS to put the content in the textarea.

Comment: @MichaelCoker How do I use JS to put the content in the textarea?

Comment: use google.....

Comment: @MichaelCoker I mean what do I search? I know I can change the textarea value using `.val()` but how do I use the same text, but with just the images updated?